How does `git mergetool` work with `git apply -3`?
I applied a patch with git apply --3way, there were conflicts, I ran git mergetool -t meld, and now I have no idea what I'm looking at.

Meld (git mergetool -t meld) presents a 3-column view:
------------------------------------------
|             |           |              |
|   LOCAL     |   BASE    |   REMOTE     |
|             |           |              |
------------------------------------------

When merging, rebasing, or cherry-picking:

LOCAL is file as it is on the current branch
REMOTE is file as it is on the incoming branch
BASE is the file as it was on the most recent common ancestor of the two

You are expected to use the mergetool's user interface to copy hunks from LOCAL or REMOTE into BASE to produce a merged file.
However, after a git apply -3, the columns are different:

LOCAL is file as it is on the current branch
REMOTE is file as it is on the patch's branch, after the patch
BASE is the file as it was on the patch's branch, right before the patch

The fact that BASE is not the most recent common ancestor in this case can be extremely confusing. It is possible to visually compare the middle and right columns to see which changes came from the patch as opposed to the patch's parent, but it's not obvious, and you often have to copy a large number of hunks from the left to the middle to avoid applying changes from the patch's parent that were not in the patch itself.
One way to avoid extra work is to enable mergetool.meld.useAutoMerge, which automatically discards changes not in the patch itself (if middle equals right, use left), applies changes from the patch that do not conflict with the current branch (if left equals middle, use right), and discards changes from the patch that the current branch already has (if left equals right, use left). If you enable mergetool.meld.hideResolved too, the changes that were automatically reconciled won't even appear in Meld, so you'll only see the merge conflicts. These options work for all types of three-way merges, not just git apply -3. A word of warning: If you enable hideResolved without useAutoMerge, the left and right columns will be the same wherever there was a non-conflicting change, but you will still have to copy the change to the middle column.
But there is a better way. Instead of a 3-column view, Vimdiff (mergetool -t vimdiff) presents a 4-pane view:
------------------------------------------
|             |           |              |
|   LOCAL     |   BASE    |   REMOTE     |
|             |           |              |
------------------------------------------
|                                        |
|                MERGED                  |
|                                        |
------------------------------------------

The top half of the window is LOCAL, REMOTE, and BASE, as before. But instead of editing BASE to produce a merged file, now the merged file is presented in the bottom half, conflict markers and all. For each conflict, you can choose to use the hunk from LOCAL, REMOTE, or BASE, or leave the conflict unresolved. For changes that were applied without conflict, you don't have to do a thing. In my opinion the 4-pane view makes more sense for any kind of conflict resolution, but it is especially nice with git apply -3 because it doesn't force you to think about changes that weren't part of the patch.
If you've never used Vimdiff before, see this excellent answer for how to get started. There's also Perforce Merge (git mergetool -t p4merge) which is a GUI tool with a similar 4-pane user interface, but beware that p4merge has the top three columns in the opposite order as vimdiff.

KDiff3 also has a nice 4-pane merge view which I use all the time for resolving conflicts.
